# What does it mean by "Adding Gaussian Noise to a 2D Image"?

Tags: image-processing, noise, gaussian

As far as I understand,

Suppose, we have a 2D image of pixel resolution 200 x 300. That means, the image has 60000 pixels in it.

Now, we would generate $n$ random values and add those values to $n$ number of random pixels.

Now, my question is, what would make those $n$ values to look like Gaussian Random Values?

What would be the logic that I should use?

Comment: See also: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28915/white-noise-in-images

Comment: Please, when you have a question from Gonzalez book, i recommend you to cite this book in you questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find Gaussian noise generators in many image processing softwares.At each pixel, you add a realization from such random noise generators. You can look for more details at [How to Generate White Gaussian Noise](http://dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-generate-white-gaussian-noise).

On StackExchange, additional sources of information:

- [Why Gaussian noise is usually used?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17990/why-gaussian-noise-is-usually-used)
- [Why is Gaussian noise called so?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29475/why-is-gaussian-noise-called-so)
- [What's gaussian noise look like?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28861/whats-gaussian-noise-look-like)
- [The model of noise in Image denoising problem](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26968/the-model-of-noise-in-image-denoising-problem)

Comment: Is my understanding of Gaussian noise correct?

Comment: It seems so, if $n$ is the number of pixels.

Comment: Image has 60000 pixels. Of which, I would add noise to $n$ pixels. That's why I am generating the same number of random-values.  Am I right?

Comment: Sounds correct. Generally the noise is zero-average, so yoou will need to choose the level of the noise, with a factor affecting the random numbers generated, for instance, by a unit-variance Gaussian.